# FTP upload in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, line-by-line

I tried to write a bash script which upload a file to an ip address with ftp connection, but i have an issue or something like that. I have a .txt file with a lot of line. Every line have an ip address, nothing else just the ip address. So i want to read the ip address from the text file and use it as a variable. This is my ugly code:

```
#!/bin/bash


input="example.txt";

user="admin"
pass="12345678"    
filename="example.src"

while IFS= read -r line; do

  connection

done < $input

connection(){
ftp -i -n $line 

user $user $pass

put $filename

bye

}
```

With the first ip address int the first line the connection and the upload is successful but the other lines got error like this:

```
Login incorrect
Login failed.
Please login with USER and PASS
Passive mode refused.
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I'm sorry :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands of ftp can be written in a here-document.

```
#!/bin/bash

connection(){
ftp -i -n $line << EOS
user $user $pass
put $filename
bye
EOS
}

input="example.txt";

user="admin"
pass="12345678"    
filename="example.src"

while IFS= read -r line; do

  connection

done < $input
```

Comment: Can you explain what do the "here-document" mean? :D I'm a little bit new

Comment: The "here-document" means the block from "<< EOS" to "EOS" in my script. See "https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html".